# Chrome displays my site in different resolution than other sites

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxMwo.jpg)I'm trying to build a site (just for practice) and experiencing something strange. 
I have about 5 sites open in google chrome and when I examine them with chrome dev tools I can see that all of them is 1440px (body). But my site is 1600 px.

It works well in Firefox and Safari so the problem only occurs in Chrome.

I tried to delete browser cache but it didn't solve the problem.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are not zoomed in or out on the page?

Comment: share screenshot of chrome.

Comment: Did you press it `ctrl + mousewheel`?

Comment: I attached a screenshot